# How do I retrieve previous localStorage value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

This is my code...

```
function sendit() {
/*SEND DATA TO LOCAL STORAGE*/
    var mobject = { 'yes': 1};      
    $('.yes').on('click',function() {
            mobject.yes++;
            localStorage.setItem('mobject', JSON.stringify(mobject));
            var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('mobject');
            console.log('retrievedObject: ', JSON.parse(retrievedObject));
    });//end click
/**/
}//end yes
```

The results show up fine as I am clicking on my page and checking out the console log.  But if I was to refresh the page, what must I change in my code to start the numerical value from where I left off?

Comment: What do you get in the console, when refreshing the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a check on the local storage variable to see if it exists. If it does set `mobject` to that value else set to your default:

```
function sendit() {
/*SEND DATA TO LOCAL STORAGE*/
    var mobject = localStorage.getItem('mobject') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('mobject'))  : { 'yes': 1};      
    $('.yes').on('click',function() {
            mobject.yes++;
            localStorage.setItem('mobject', JSON.stringify(mobject));
            var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('mobject');
            console.log('retrievedObject: ', JSON.parse(retrievedObject));
    });//end click
/**/
}//end yes
```

Comment: I did not know you can set a conditional statement on a variable like that.  Thanks for the lesson!

Comment: It's a conditional expression using the ternary operator (?:), very handy if you don't make them too complicated. The MDN article on it is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator